# Weird unhandled exception's StackTrace behavior in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, exception, uwp, unhandled-exception

In my UWP app's `App.xaml.cs` file I have the following code to get unhandled exceptions' `StackTrace` property value and print it to the debug output:

```
private void OnAppUnhandledException(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception exceptionThatDoesntGoAway = e.Exception;

    string stackTrace = exceptionThatDoesntGoAway.StackTrace;

    Debug.WriteLine("Exception Stacktrace: " + stackTrace);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I save the Exception to a separate variable as there is [another weird behavior where the exception's content gets removed if accessed more than once](http://blog.wpdev.fr/inspecting-unhandled-exceptions-youve-got-only-one-chance/) in case I would need it again.

Then, I save the exception's `StackTrace` property value to a variable, and then I print it to the debug output.

The problem is that before and after accessing the `StackTrace` property I get two different outputs:

I watched the `exceptionThatDoesntGoAway` variable and the `StackTrace` property in Visual Studio:

[image]

This is the `StackTrace` property value from the `exceptionThatDoesntGoAway` variable (the first watched item):

[image]

While this is the `exceptionThatDoesntGoAway.StackTrace` property value without line numbers  for my app's files (the second watched item):

[image]

Why are the values different even if they are the same `StackTrace` property?

How can I get the first stacktrace with the correct line numbers? Is an expected behavior?

**Edit 1**:
Those are the app's threads at `exceptionThatDoesntGoAway.StackTrace` access time:

[image]

Comment: Does your app happen to have multiple threads? These 2 exceptions look totally different. You can check the Thread ID with the Threads window (in Debug\Windows menu).

Comment: @LukeVo I updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: I can reproduce the same problem, direct access to `exceptionThatDoesntGoAway.StackTrace` property will miss information "in FileName :line LineNumber ", but complete string can be seen in the Object `exceptionThatDoesntGoAway`.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Is there a way to solve this problem? How can I get and print the complete string with line numbers?

Comment: This is a known issue. I checked the issue library, someone has already filed this issue before, we will look into this.